# how to put a Chart3D in a jpanel

Tags: java, swing, orson-charts

i'm working on a java swing app and i found a problem to put a Chart3D in a jpanel or a frame, this is my code

```
private void initChart(){

  CategoryDataset3D dataset = createDataset();
        Chart3D chart = Chart3DFactory.createStackedBarChart(
                "Personnel répartition,", 
                "repartition pour 480 personnel ", 
                dataset, null, 
                "Class", "Personnel");
     ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("/Users/dgilbert/Desktop/iStock_000003105870Small.jpg"); 
        RectanglePainter background = new StandardRectanglePainter(Color.WHITE, 
                icon.getImage(), new Fit2D(TitleAnchor.CENTER, 
                Scale2D.SCALE_BOTH));
            chart.setChartBoxColor(new Color(255, 255, 255, 155));
               CategoryPlot3D plot = (CategoryPlot3D) chart.getPlot();
//        StackedBarRenderer3D renderer = (StackedBarRenderer3D) plot.getRenderer();
//        renderer.setColorSource(new StandardCategoryColorSource( new Color[] { new Color(50, 200, 50),new Color(200, 50, 50) }));
            final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
            Frame frame = new ChartFrame("tokens pert time", chart);
            frame.setSize(550,450);
```

the problem is :
final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart); Frame frame = new ChartFrame("tokens pert time", chart); in those two lines , it appears an error "Chart3D cannor be converted to j freeChart" –

Comment: What problem are you facing? What is the exact error.

Comment: if there is an exception post your exception stack trace

Comment: final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
 Frame frame = new ChartFrame("tokens pert time", chart); in those two lines , it appears an error "Chart3D cannor be converted to j freeChart"

Comment: Ghassane Mhilis Please edit new information into the question, don't add it in comments.

Answer (score 1):

As you appear to be using [orson-charts](/questions/tagged/orson-charts), you may be looking for [`Chart3DPanel`](http://www.object-refinery.com/orsoncharts/javadoc/com/orsoncharts/Chart3DPanel.html), as shown in [*Getting Started*](http://www.object-refinery.com/orsoncharts/javadoc/overview-summary.html).

```
Chart3DPanel chartPanel = new Chart3DPanel(chart);
```